# Can I legally run wiring through a window or its frame?

Tags: wiring, windows

I am planning on hooking up a hot tub in our in backyard and we need to run a wire from the breaker panel to the tub. Although we could run the wire through the concrete, there is an unused basement window and it would be easier to run the wire through the window or its frame.

I imagine other people wanting a hot tub may also have a similar situation. I've attached a picture of both sides of the window for reference. I've also attached a picture of another location in the house where someone has done exactly as described.

Is it okay, as for as the ESA (Electrical Safety Authority) in Ontario (Canada) goes, to run the electrical wire for the hot tub through this window?

Thanks so much.[image]

Comment: I think as long as it looks, walks and quacks like a window, there'll be issues with that.

Comment: i think that if you replace a column of glass with plywood then you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

First, does the window open, and is it required by fire codes for emergency egress?

If so, you could remove the window and install a shorter or narrower window, that still meets code, and then use the margin to pass through your utilities.  I would use fairly tough metal conduit for electrical to make it resistant to damage.

I already see a wood margin that might suffice.

Otherwise you'd want to permanently remove the window from service as a window, by doing a surface treatment on both sides that renders it not a window.   Either remove the window entirely or panel it over on both sides so it is entirely buried, remove a pane, put the service through, and fill the voids with insulation.

I hate to remove a classic window like that made of solid material and well installed, so I would go for the remove-a-pane option.

Comment: Thanks for the input. As is not needed for emergency egress as it is in the cold seler and there are several other emergency windows in the basement. Since it's in the cold seller I may do the remove the window option.

Answer (score 1):

Its a basement window...Most code in the USA requires windows to be free of obstructions in the event of fire.  You should contact your local city to determine code as when and if you sell, you will be required to pass code when an inspector comes to your home.  My advice...drill a hole in the wood or brick and run properly.  A window is not an area to run power.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, far better to drill foundation wall.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Why do you believe it is better to drill the foundation wall?

Comment: It would simply make a nicer job.  I think you degrade the value of your house to an extent with this type of work.  Lacks professionalism.